# should I use phonegap local storage for storing checkbox field options

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, local-storage

I'm beginning with jQuery mobile and Phonegap.

I have a category selector and based on the selected category I show a checkboxlist that belongs to that category.
See below 1 example of a checkbox group I might show. Notice that it's hidden and that I will only show that field if the user selects 'locations' in field 'category'.

```
<select name="select-choice-0" id="category" onchange="javascript:showboxes();updateresults();">
<option value="0">Select a category</option>
<option value="4">Catering</option>   
<option value="1">Locations</option>
<option value="2">Music</option>
</select>


<div id="locationthemes_box" data-role="collapsible" style="display:none;">
<h3>Themes</h3>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend>Theme</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" name="locationthemes" id="checkbox-1" value="2" class="custom" />
    <label for="checkbox-1">Castle</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="locationthemes" id="checkbox-2" value="3" class="custom" />
    <label for="checkbox-2">Barn</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="locationthemes" id="checkbox-3" value="5" class="custom" />
    <label for="checkbox-3">Restaurant</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="locationthemes" id="checkbox-4" value="8" class="custom" />
    <label for="checkbox-4">Bar</label>
</fieldset>
</div>
</div>
```

Now, I have more checkboxgroups I want to show or hide depending on the selected category. I want to prevent that I have the HTML of the checkboxes that are NOT shown in the page.
Since that would result in unnessecary bandwidth usage. 
I then thought: perhaps I should load the contents of the checkbox groups dynamically, by making a web service request for relevant checkboxes and values as soon as user changes the category selectbox.

But that would result in a lot of webrequests, and I was trying to save bandwidth.

So my thought was that local storage might be able to solve my problem.
I would then store the checkbox values as a name/value string:
locationthemes = 2;Castle;3;Barn;5;Restaurant;8;Bar

My question: is this the way to go or is there a best practice that I don't know of?
If my way is the adviced way: any examples of using local storage with PhoneGap are more than welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Jquery Mobile's Single Page Concept of having one HTML and containing all pages in it like this

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
<div data-role="page" id="page3">
<div data-role="page" id="page4">
```

Then you can use a **Global variable** to store the values.

Else you can use the localStorage as explained here
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage

Comment: I do use the Single Page Concept. So I will do as you suggested and define a global variable like: var locationthemes = 2;Castle;3;Barn;5;Restaurant;8;Bar
If I do that and define the global variables in an external js file instead of in the page. Is the .js file cached locally so that only the HTML file needs to be loaded and not the js file which contains my data?

Comment: If you choose to declare your global variables in an external .js file then i will prefer not to do it. If this is the case then use localStorage. But if you dont have an external js files then use global variables in the HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using localStorage simply for the reason that Android kills your app mercilessly if needed. Once the user puts your app in the background for a while, or if he sends his phone to sleep or waits for too long, then the app might get killed. This is where you can make sure you always store the app's status or important variables in localStorage and then pick up this data again when the app is restarted (with a simple startup check)..

Comment: Of course, a background service is a useful alternative as well, but localStorage is just nice and simple to use, and I would recommend it if your app is not too complicated in its design..